# Cakephp multiple or search

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to be able to search all data based on multiple or conditions using foreach like below:

```
 function index() {
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id') != 1) {
            $commune_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.commune_id');
            $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->findbyId($commune_id);
            $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->find('all',array('conditions' => array('group' => $commune_id['Commune']['group'])));
            $count = count($commune_id);
            $i=1;
            foreach($commune_id as $commune_ids){
            if($i != $count){
            $this->paginate = array(
                'or' => array(
                    array('Petition.commune_id LIKE' => $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] . ","),
                    ),
                'limit' => 10
            );
            }
            $i++;
            }
        }
        $this->Petition->recursive = 0;
        $petitions = $this->paginate();
        $this->set('petitions', $petitions);
    }
```

I was able to get possible number of matches but was wondering how I can use this array to get results with multiple or conditions with paginator function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do pagination in custom situations like this, one normally has to override `Model::paginate()` and `Model::paginateCount()` as detailed in the book under [Custom Query pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination).

Alternatively, you could use a plugin that already has features such as pagination implemented, such as CakeDC's [Search plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search).